# Iterating through an array of objects and select an object by number of occurrences in the array

Tags: javascript

```js
const bondFilms = [
  { "title" : "Skyfall", "year" : 2012, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$1,108,561,008" },
  { "title" : "Thunderball", "year" : 1965, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$1,014,941,117" },
  { "title" : "Goldfinger", "year" : 1964, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$912,257,512" },
  { "title" : "Live and Let Die", "year" : 1973, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$825,110,761" },
  { "title" : "You Only Live Twice", "year" : 1967, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$756,544,419" },
  { "title" : "The Spy Who Loved Me", "year" : 1977, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$692,713,752" },
  { "title" : "Casino Royale", "year" : 2006, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$669,789,482" },
  { "title" : "Moonraker", "year" : 1979, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$655,872,400" },
  { "title" : "Diamonds Are Forever", "year" : 1971, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$648,514,469" },
  { "title" : "Quantum of Solace", "year" : 2008, "actor" : "Daniel Craig", "gross" : "$622,246,378" },
  { "title" : "From Russia with Love", "year" : 1963, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$576,277,964" },
  { "title" : "Die Another Day", "year" : 2002, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$543,639,638" },
  { "title" : "Goldeneye", "year" : 1995, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$529,548,711" },
  { "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", "year" : 1969, "actor" : "George Lazenby", "gross" : "$505,899,782" },
  { "title" : "The World is Not Enough", "year" : 1999, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$491,617,153" },
  { "title" : "For Your Eyes Only", "year" : 1981, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$486,468,881" },
  { "title" : "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year" : 1997, "actor" : "Pierce Brosnan", "gross" : "$478,946,402" },
  { "title" : "The Man with the Golden Gun", "year" : 1974, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$448,249,281" },
  { "title" : "Dr. No", "year" : 1962, "actor" : "Sean Connery", "gross" : "$440,759,072" },
  { "title" : "Octopussy", "year" : 1983, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$426,244,352" },
  { "title" : "The Living Daylights", "year" : 1987, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$381,088,866" },
  { "title" : "A View to a Kill", "year" : 1985, "actor" : "Roger Moore", "gross" : "$321,172,633" },
  { "title" : "License to Kill", "year" : 1989, "actor" : "Timothy Dalton", "gross" : "$285,157,191" }
];

const leastBondAppearance = []
for (let i = 0; i < bondFilms.length; i++){
    leastBondAppearance.push(bondFilms[i].actor)
}
// console.log(leastBondAppearance)
let findDuplicates = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) != index)
 console.log(findDuplicates(leastBondAppearance))
```

This gives me an array of strings that contain all of the actors name with duplicates. I can't figure out how to then count how many times those strings appear. I then need to return a single object with the actor who has appeared bond films the fewest amount of times.

I know I also need to write some logic to address which actor has appeared the fewest times but I'm lost a couple steps before that.

Below is what the final result should look like.

```
 { 
  "title" : "On Her Majesty's Secret Service", 
  "year" : 1969, 
  "actor" : "George Lazenby", 
  "gross" : "$505,899,782" 
}
```

That's because George Lazenby was only in a single bond film.

Comment: I would suggest maintaining a mapping of "actor name" => "number of films appeared in". You accomplish this with an object: `const filmCounts = {};`. Then  you can update that mapping by modifying `filmCounts[bondFilms[i].actor]` as appropriate

Comment: @Darius Raazi why you want to show the object instead of just the name?

Comment: If you think one of the anwers were helpful, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
let actors = {}

bondFilms.forEach(f => {
    if (!actors[f.actor]) actors[f.actor] = 0
    actors[f.actor] = actors[f.actor]+1 // or actors[f.actor]++
    })

let sortedActorNames = Object.keys(actors).sort((a,b) => actors[a]-actors[b])

console.log(sortedActorNames[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the unique actors and then check which of them appears at least with a nested for loop and a counter variable.

```
const uniqueBonds = [];
let res ;
let counter = 0;
let max = 9007199254740991;


bondFilms.forEach((x) => {
  if (!uniqueBonds.includes(x.actor.trim())) {
    uniqueBonds.push(x.actor)
  }

})


uniqueBonds.forEach((x) => {
  let temp;
  bondFilms.forEach((y) => {

    if (x === y.actor.trim()) {
      counter += 1;
      temp = y;
    }

  })
  if (counter < max) {

    max = counter;
    res = temp;
  }
  counter = 0;
})
```

```js
const bondFilms = [{
    "title": "Skyfall",
    "year": 2012,
    "actor": "Daniel Craig",
    "gross": "$1,108,561,008"
  },
  {
    "title": "Thunderball",
    "year": 1965,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$1,014,941,117"
  },
  {
    "title": "Goldfinger",
    "year": 1964,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$912,257,512"
  },
  {
    "title": "Live and Let Die",
    "year": 1973,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$825,110,761"
  },
  {
    "title": "You Only Live Twice",
    "year": 1967,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$756,544,419"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Spy Who Loved Me",
    "year": 1977,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$692,713,752"
  },
  {
    "title": "Casino Royale",
    "year": 2006,
    "actor": "Daniel Craig",
    "gross": "$669,789,482"
  },
  {
    "title": "Moonraker",
    "year": 1979,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$655,872,400"
  },
  {
    "title": "Diamonds Are Forever",
    "year": 1971,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$648,514,469"
  },
  {
    "title": "Quantum of Solace",
    "year": 2008,
    "actor": "Daniel Craig",
    "gross": "$622,246,378"
  },
  {
    "title": "From Russia with Love",
    "year": 1963,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$576,277,964"
  },
  {
    "title": "Die Another Day",
    "year": 2002,
    "actor": "Pierce Brosnan",
    "gross": "$543,639,638"
  },
  {
    "title": "Goldeneye",
    "year": 1995,
    "actor": "Pierce Brosnan",
    "gross": "$529,548,711"
  },
  {
    "title": "On Her Majesty's Secret Service",
    "year": 1969,
    "actor": "George Lazenby",
    "gross": "$505,899,782"
  },
  {
    "title": "The World is Not Enough",
    "year": 1999,
    "actor": "Pierce Brosnan",
    "gross": "$491,617,153"
  },
  {
    "title": "For Your Eyes Only",
    "year": 1981,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$486,468,881"
  },
  {
    "title": "Tomorrow Never Dies",
    "year": 1997,
    "actor": "Pierce Brosnan",
    "gross": "$478,946,402"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Man with the Golden Gun",
    "year": 1974,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$448,249,281"
  },
  {
    "title": "Dr. No",
    "year": 1962,
    "actor": "Sean Connery",
    "gross": "$440,759,072"
  },
  {
    "title": "Octopussy",
    "year": 1983,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$426,244,352"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Living Daylights",
    "year": 1987,
    "actor": "Timothy Dalton",
    "gross": "$381,088,866"
  },
  {
    "title": "A View to a Kill",
    "year": 1985,
    "actor": "Roger Moore",
    "gross": "$321,172,633"
  },
  {
    "title": "License to Kill",
    "year": 1989,
    "actor": "Timothy Dalton",
    "gross": "$285,157,191"
  }
];


const uniqueBonds = [];
let res ;
let counter = 0;
let max = 9007199254740991;


bondFilms.forEach((x) => {
  if (!uniqueBonds.includes(x.actor.trim())) {
    uniqueBonds.push(x.actor)
  }

})


uniqueBonds.forEach((x) => {
  let temp;
  bondFilms.forEach((y) => {

    if (x === y.actor.trim()) {
      counter += 1;
      temp = y;
    }

  })
  if (counter < max) {

    max = counter;
    res = temp;
  }
  counter = 0;
})

console.log(res)
```